# Request signal property in Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

As it can be seen in the reference, [`Request`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) instance has `signal` property:

> request . signal
>
> Returns the signal associated with request, which is an AbortSignal object indicating whether or not request has been aborted, and its abort event handler.

This snippet shows that `req.signal.aborted` is `false` even after a request has been aborted:

```
let req = new Request('/');
req.signal.onabort = () => console.log('abort'); // no output
let ctrl = new AbortController();
fetch(req, { signal: ctrl.signal })
  .catch(() => console.log(req.signal.aborted)); // outputs false
ctrl.abort();
```

The result is the same with simulated connection problem (`net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`).

What is the practical reason for default `req.signal` to be exposed? Can a request behave differently with reassigned `req.signal`?

How can `req.signal` request signal become aborted, i.e. trigger `onabort` callback and set `req.signal` to `true`?

I'm interested in how native Fetch API implementations work internally, there's no specific code problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This snippet shows that `req.signal.aborted` is false even after a request has been aborted.

Yes. That's because not `req` is the aborted request, but the request constructed internally by `fetch()`.

Instead, write

```
let ctrl = new AbortController();
let req = new Request('/', { signal: ctrl.signal });
req.signal.onabort = () => console.log('abort'); // will log
fetch(req).catch(() => console.log(req.signal.aborted)); // outputs true
ctrl.abort();
```

The `req.signal` that was created with the `new Request` constructor here does follow the abort signal of your controller.

Comment: Yes, thanks, providing a signal from controller instance a correct way to do this. I'm aware of this though, my question referred exclusively to default req.signal value. Do you confirm that `signal` in user-created Request instances is just dummy AbortSignal instance that is never used and doesn't affect anything? I was unable to debug what happens with Request instance created by fetch internally as it seems to rely on internal implementation that cannot be tampered through Request.prototype.

Comment: I think so, yes. According to the spec, a `new Request().signal` is just initialised by default but will never get aborted.

Comment: Can you quote the part that suggests that? Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: @EstusFlask Nothing specifically. It's just "[*A `Request` object has an associated signal, initially a new `AbortSignal` object.*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-signal)", and [step 30 of the `Request` constructor](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request) which is the only step in the entire spec manipulating the signal (namely, making it follow the optional signal of the passed `input` or `init`).